# Wordpress plugin for real estate that scales?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Anyone have recommendations for wordpress plugins that can scale easily and integrates with Wordpress' new custom post types?

Not interested in themes as discussed here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26/real-estate-website-with-word-press

Comment: Define "scale."

Comment: Also please mention if you need integration with a rets/ids/mls system. Also what features do you need.

Comment: @jalefkowit Scale as in it is durable and you're able to enter 13,000 entries. @wyck Yes must integrate with MLS system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with something custom in drupal. Seems like the best way to go.